# Problem in showing data in ui in ListView Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am sending data from my controller to my ui part i can't understand what the problem is and how to solve it. I tried every answer given on stackoverflow and many other websites but nothing seems to work for me:( i am sure my login part has no problem but my ui is not able to render the data According to my needs.
Code:

```
final singleViewController = Get.put(SingleViewController());

class SingleView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List stanza;
  final String paragraphId;
  const SingleView({
    Key? key,
    required this.stanza,
    required this.paragraphId,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            stanza.toString().trim(),
            style: const TextStyle(
          
              fontSize: 25,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: 800,
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              GetBuilder<SingleViewController>(builder: (controller) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height:600,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: singleViewController.foundedparagraph.length,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                      return Text(
                        singleViewController.foundedparagraph[index]["stanza"]
                            .toString(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the error i am receiving:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIdqF.png)

Comment: are you received data from API and display it into listview?

Comment: I was using data from json file. My problem is solved now i moved some code. Thanks for the reply though